# Modified default for bash case statement

Tags: bash, case

I have seen the general case statement in `bash` that an asterisk `*` to denotes the default pattern.  If an expression isn’t matched with any of the other patterns in the case statement the default clause is executed.

```
case $1 in
  ("-u2") printf "%s\n" "TODO" ;;
  ("-u3") printf "%s\n" "TODO" ;;
  ("-u1"|"-u"|*) printf "%s\n" "$KCFRONT_A" ;;
esac
```

I have modified it such that the default also gets called for case of `-u1` and `-u`.  This strategy seems to work.  Is this a valid and understandable thing to do?

Comment: What's the point? If it's `-u1` or `-u`, it'll also match `*`, so there's no change in behavior here.

Comment: Even if valid, it makes no sense. You're basically saying: "Provided it's neither `-u2` nor `-u3`, do this if it's `-u1`, `-u`, or *anything.*" The "anything" is a proper *superset* of `{-u1, -u}`, so specifying them is superfluous.

Comment: I see your point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works, but it's not necessary. `*` matches any string, so naming them doesn't do anything.